# python Api output json/string

Tags: python, json

I have problem with an api output. As the web page says its a json but suddenly he switch to string?
The output looks like this

```
{'terms':
 [{'start_date':'2013-09-30', 
'finish_date': '2014-03-02',
'end_date': '2014-01-31',
'order_key': 420,
'name': {'pl': 'Semestr zimowy 2013/14', 'en': 'Winter Semester 2013/14'},
 'id': '2013Z'},
.
.
.
{'start_date': '2017-09-25', 
'finish_date': '2018-02-19',
'end_date': '2018-01-29',
'order_key': 540,
'name': {'pl': 'Semest zimowy 2017/2018', 'en': 'Winter Semester 2017/18'}, 'id': '2017Z'}],
```

and then something like second paragraph looks like this

```
'groups':
 {'2015Z':
 [{'relationship_type': 'participant',
 'course_name': {'pl': 'Algorytmy i struktury danych', 'en': 'Algorithms and Data Structures'},
 'term_id': '2015Z'},
.
.
.
{'relationship_type': 'participant',
 'course_name': {'pl': 'Wychowanie fizyczne 1', 'en': 'Gymnastics 1'},
 'term_id': '2015Z'}]
```

Whole output got +1000 words so i decided to put it that way. My problem is that i can get an any data from `terms` but when i try to get any data from `groups` pycharms says those are strings. My code looks like this

```
data = polaczenie.get('/services/groups/user',
fields='course_name|class_type|class_type_id|group_number', format='json')
mylist = []
mylist2 = []
for i in data['terms']:
    mylist.append(i['id'])
print(mylist)
for i in data['groups']:
    mylist2.append(i['course_name'])
print(mylist2)
```

The first loop get data fine however the second give me following error

`mylist2.append(i['term_id'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

As I understand the error, my json suddenly become string? I don't know how I can fix it and my goal is to get `course_name` and `term_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in data['groups']['2015Z']:
    mylist2.append(i['course_name'])
```

Comment: Thank You soo much :> I'm really a begginer in json in python ^^

Comment: json is hard to read, you may need pprint library to get readable json file, and please accept my answer.